# How to connect to a peerjs server from external host

Tags: server, portforwarding, raspberry-pi4, peerjs

I'm trying to use a raspberry pi 4 as a simple peerjs server.
Here's my command that works well in local: `peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs --path /videocallapp`

[I opened my router like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nfcY.png)

But I can't connect to it using my simple peerjs javascript client set up like that : `host: '192.***.*.**', port: 9000, path: '/videocallapp'`
Host here is the ip of raspberry

Can you please help me?

What I precisly don't know is: does the host ip written in the client is wrong or is it the port that is wrongly set up

Answer (score 0):

I solved it : here's the configuration

server: `peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs --path /videocallapp`

router: Web Server (HTTP)   internal:9000   external:80 protocol:TCP    equipment: raspberrypi

client: ip:your public Ip! (https://canyouseeme.org/) port:80